# Get the current iteration count

Tags: evaluation

I would like to be able to get the current iteration count, the one that if exceeds `$IterationLimit` makes the evaluation stop.

After not finding a magical variable that stores this value, or a magical built-in that retrieves it, I thought about `TraceScan`.

According to the documentation of `$IterationLimit`,

> ```
> $IterationLimit gives an upper limit on the length of any list that can be generated by Trace
> ```

However, a quick test shows that this is not so simple. Let's define

```
ClearAll[f]
f[i_] := f[i - 1]
f[0] := "Yeah"
```

Now,

```
Block[{$IterationLimit = 20},
 Trace[f[18]] // Length//Print;
 Trace[f[18], TraceDepth -> 1] // Length//Print;
 f[18]
 ]
```

prints 56 and 38 respectively, while `f[18]`'s evaluation finishes successfully.

Looking at the output of the last trace, we see that the before and after argument evaluation are being traced. So,

```
Trace[f[3], TraceDepth -> 1]   
(* {f[3],f[3-1],f[2],f[2-1],f[1],f[1-1],f[0],Yeah} *)
```

Notice that the "two outputs per iteration" rule doesn't hold if we add a definition like `f[3]=f[1]`, in which case

```
Trace[f[5], TraceDepth -> 1]
(* {f[5],f[5-1],f[4],f[4-1],f[3],f[1],f[1-1],f[0],Yeah} *)
```

If this happened, a hacky workround could exist along the lines of

```
SetAttributes[trackIterations, HoldFirst];
trackIterations[code_] := Block[{iterationCounter = 0},
  TraceScan[iterationCounter += 1/2, code, TraceDepth -> 1]
  ]
```

**Question**

How can I get that counter, or alternatively, how can I make `Trace` only trace once each iteration?

Comment: I wanted to be the one to answer this but I'm stumped.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_Misc_3.html. He says "I don't discuss how  counting iterarions and recursions fit into the evaluation process because I  have never seen an explanation of when that happens."

Comment: @belisarius (She says...) http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/bios.html

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I thought it was Ted's

Comment: @belisarius Sorry, you are probably correct. I thought you were referring to Verbeia and did not check to see specifically who wrote what.

Comment: @Andre, the iteration count should not be per symbol I believe. You can do `f[i_]:=g[i-1];f[0]=g[0]="Yeah";g[i_]:=f[i-1];$IterationLimit=20;f[21]`, and hit the limit with only 10 iterations of `f` or `g`

Comment: Nice score: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iWyPM.png

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure whether you can generalize this or how stable this approach is, but it seems if you use `Trace` to look how often the exactly the form `f` is evaluated then that does the trick.

```
ClearAll[f]
f[i_] := f[i - 1]
f[0] := "Yeah"

Block[{$IterationLimit = 20},
 Cases[Trace[f[100], f, TraceOriginal -> True], HoldForm[f], Infinity] // Length // Print;
 f[100]]
```

The idea behind this is as follows: I was reading Rojos question and inspecting the trace of depth 1

```
(* {f[5],f[5-1],f[4],f[4-1],f[3],f[3-1],f[2],f[2-1],f[1],f[1-1],f[0],Yeah} *)
```

The problem was that although `f` was called fewer times, every evaluation step is shown and the length of the above list cannot be used. Therefore, I though about a way to count how often the `Head` of the expression, i.e. the symbol `f` itself was evaluated. Usually, the evaluation of the `Head` is not shown, since its form does not change.

This can be turned on using `TraceOriginal`

```
Trace[f[3],f,TraceOriginal->True]
(* {f[3],{f},f[3],f[3-1],{f},f[2],f[2-1],{f},f[1],f[1-1],{f},f[0],Yeah} *)
```

Now we can count each single instance of `f` which occurs in the output. In my first example I used `Cases` because I was just adapting Rojos examples with its `//Length//Print`. Of course, and as suggested by Mr.Wizard `Count` is the better alternative here

```
Block[{$IterationLimit = 20}, 
 Count[Trace[f[100], f, TraceOriginal -> True], {HoldForm[f]}]
]
```

While I was writing this, another idea came to my mind. When the problem is, that the head does not change and it therefore does not appear in the usual output, why not fixing this?
Therefore, here an alternative approach which adjusts the function to be evaluated and makes a use of options to `Trace` unnecessary:

```
ClearAll[f, g]
g = f;
f[i_] := g[i - 1]
f[0] := "Yeah"

Block[{$IterationLimit = 25},
 Count[Flatten[Trace[g[100]]], HoldForm[g]]
]
```

Comment: Interesting.  I suggest you change `Cases` to `Count` for brevity.  Also, do you need `Infinity` or would scanning at level 1 be sufficient?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard likely the `Infinity` is required otherwise it won't scan deep enough.

Comment: NiiiiIIiIIiiIIIiiiiice. A `ThreadDepth->2` might help it be more efficient

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I explained that `Count` is better now. I just wanted to wait, whether it helps Rojo at all. You might be interested in the last part I added.

Comment: I can't think of a way to generalize the last approach, I prefer the first :)