# Display level of recursion of a recursive function during execution

Tags: functions, function-construction, recursion

Given a recursive function, is there some simple way to display or store the value of recursion or "how many levels deep" the function is at a given time?

For instance, if we wrote the recursive function to calculate the factorial of a number (for any positive integer x):

```
r[x_] := If[x > 0, x*r[x - 1], 1]
```

Is there some way to output, as the function evaluates that it is a level "n"?

Given that the `$RecursionLimit` determines the max number of times a function can call itself nested, there must be some flag or value stored to keep track of how deep the current evaluation is that is compared to `$RecursionLimit`, that, if exceeded, aborts.  What is this flag/value?

Comment: From [`Stack` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Stack.html): "The maximum length of `Stack[]` is limited by `$RecursionLimit`."

Comment: @Oleksandr The question how is (I believe) how can you access the present depth before $RecursionLimit is reached.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard the documentation I quoted implies that the correct thing to do is `Length@Stack[]`. I am not sure if `Stack[]` is really the most fundamental manifestation of the evaluation stack, but even if not, I think it should suffice. Add `StackBegin`/`StackInhibit` to taste.

Comment: @Oleksandr Okay, I missed that point.  Thanks.  Have you tested it?  Can you help me find the earlier question?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414601/memoized-recursive-functions-how-to-make-them-fool-proof/? I am not sure exactly which question you must be thinking of, but this seems close.

Comment: @Oleksandr It is not the one I (think I) remember, but thank you.

Comment: @Oleksandr It occurs to me that the subject of the question I remember may have been `$IterationLimit` rather than `$RecursionLimit`.  Sorry if I wasted your time because of that, but I think the link you found is useful.

Comment: @Oleksandr Yup, this is the one: [(18397)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18397/121)

Comment: @Oleksandr Are you planning to post an answer with `Stack[]`?  I chose not to attempt this as I assumed you would.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I wasn't, as I can't really think of what to say beyond what the documentation gives us already. If you think you can do it justice, please go ahead.

Comment: @OP could you please advise on whether or not the comments above have correctly understand the issue? If not then could you please expand on why `Length@Stack[]` is not what you are looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious way to modify your code is

```
Clear[f, r]
r[x_, n_] := If[x > 0, Print[n]; x*r[x - 1, n + 1], 1]
f[k_Integer /; k > 1] := r[k, 1]
```

For small values of `x`, this works fine.

```
f[5]
```

[image: f[5]]

But it is very inefficient and also limited by `$RecursionLimit`.

```
Block[{$RecursionLimit = 20}, f[24]]
```

[image: aborted-f[24]]

Both these issues can be addressed by using a less obvious tail-recursive version of `r`.

```
Clear[f, r]
r[0, val_, _] = val;
r[k_ /; k > 0, val_, n_] := r[k - 1, k val, Print[n]; n + 1]
f[k_Integer /; k > 0] := r[k - 1, k, 1]

Block[{$RecursionLimit = 20}, f[24]]
```

[image: tail-f[24]]

Comment: +1 for tail recursion, I wasn't aware that you could use it in Mathematica (although it seems obvious now).

Comment: @2012rcampion see [(4481301)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4481301/618728) and [(21746)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21746/121)